# FFMPEG [h264_nvenc @ 0x56151389fe00] Cannot get the preset configuration: invalid version (15)

Tags: ffmpeg

i have issue with ffmpeg as usual :D. I have FFMPEG compiled (version N-90807-g00099ef0d0) with NVIDIA support (latest CUDA and latest NV Headers):

```
ffmpeg version N-90807-g00099ef0d0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-libnpp --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --disable-x86asm --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-x86asm
  libavutil      56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 19.100 /  7. 19.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

When I try to run basic transcoding on GPU using command:

```
ffmpeg -i 'udp://@239.100.0.1:331?fifo_size=‎100000000' -map i:0x100 -g 20 -vcodec  h264_nvenc -map i:0x101 -ab 128k -ar 48k -acodec aac -f mpegts udp://@239.0.0.1:1234?overrun_nonfatal_optin=
```

I got this error:

```
    Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@239.100.0.1:331?fifo_size=‎100000000':
  Duration: N/A, start: 106.414400, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x55a5edc45880] co located POCs unavailable
[h264_nvenc @ 0x55a5edc45380] Cannot get the preset configuration: invalid version (15)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x55a5edc46d40] Qavg: 227.785
[aac @ 0x55a5edc46d40] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
```

I have same version of FFMPEG compiled by the same way on another testing machine and there it is working. I tried to recompile/reinstall ffmpeg with the latest version, but result is the same.

Does someone know what could be wrong on my instance? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed. The issue was in nvidia headers. Used version was extremely new. If you'll get this issue, just use the headers with tag n8.0.14.1 and then compile ffmpeg. 
FFmpeg version of headers required to interface with Nvidias codec APIs:

```
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
git checkout n8.0.14.1
make && make install
```